# RxJava - How to get an observable that is generated through iterating from another Observable

Tags: kotlin, rx-kotlin

I am trying to generate an Observable through using and looking at last 4 data from another Observable. I am not able to figure it out yet.

I have a `data class A(val b: B)` . Then I have the following obeserver

```
// My value storer. That keeps on getting filled up
val rep = ReplayRelay.createWithSize<A>(4)


// Now I need to generate another Observable based on `rep` which looks at `b` for the last 4 sets of data anytime `rep` has new data

`fun generateObservable() : Observable<A>`
```

**What I want do**

1. is observe `rep`
2. Takes the last 4 items in `rep`
3. Check if `val b: B` and then send back one A, I do not want this to end, it should continuously keep on looking at `rep` for every item it adds.
4. Return another observer around 3

Example ->
Stream 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

`rep` stream -> (looks at 1, 2, 3,4), (looks at 2,3,4,5), (looks at 3,4,5,6)

Thanks all!

I looked into `scan` which only looks at the last 2, looked into `take` and `takeLast` that ends the Observable. `buffer` doesnt work as I need to look at the last 4 and not skip. I looked at `buffer` but I cant provide negative values.

Comment: Sounds like you need [`buffer(4, 1)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#buffer-int-int-).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a detailed marble-diagram of the values in your observables and how they should generate/read the values based on time and these observables.